# Fatal error: openssl_random_pseudo_bytes

Tags: php, ajax

I am building a web page with login feature and I came up with this error:

> **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() in ...Users_model.php

This is a snippet of source code where it leads(line 2):

```
if(password_verify($password, $row->password)) {
        $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(21));
        $this->insert_token_user($row->id, $token);
        $res = [
            'id' => $row->id,
            'first_name' => $row->first_name,
            'last_name' => $row->last_name,
            'email' => $row->email,
            'token' => $token
        ];
```

And this is the code where it happens in debug (line 3):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(email + ":" + password));
    },
    url: URL + 'user/login',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data, status, response) {
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        responseHandling(err);
    }
```

The screenshots of errors from debugger:
[image: error 1]
...

[image: error 2]

I am running Windows 10 x64 and MAMP 3.2.2 as localhost.
MAMP settings: **php 5.6.24 , cache off.**

This is what I did to try to solve the problem:

- removed semicolon in **extension=php_openssl.dll** 
  in this folder **C:\MAMP\conf\php5.6.24\php.ini**
- and here **C:\MAMP\conf\php5.6.0\php.ini**
- moved both php.ini to **C:\MAMP\bin\php\php5.6.0** and **C:\MAMP\bin\php\php5.6.24** folders

The reason for doing this in these two places is because Chrome extension "Wappalyzer" shows this page as PHP version 5.6.0.

error I get when I restart my PC with semicolons removed

[image: error I get when I restart my PC with semicolons removed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED!** Switched to PHP 7.0.9 and there is no such problem.